# Using async: false on jQuery 1.8

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if the way i wrote my ajax function with the use of async:false is ok on  jQuery 1.8?

```
function GetLoginUrl(CloudStorageName) 
{
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUrl", "Cloud")',
        data: { CloudName: CloudeName },
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            res = result;
        },
        error: function (response) 
        { 
            OpenAlertDialog('@ErrorMsg.CloudErrMsg');
        }
    });

    return res;
}
```

If this ok , can you please give an example to ajax call that is  deprecated?

Comment: It's not OK. The whole concept of synchronous AJAX is deprecated.

Comment: So, Why this is working?

Comment: That's not a good question. Plowing with a pair of oxen would "be working" as well.